# Bind ListPicker in MVVM (Selection_Changed)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm, windows-phone

I am trying to attach a command to the event Selection_Changed of the ListPicker

I have the following code for the listpicker in my xaml :

```
   <toolkit:ListPicker 
         x:name="picker" ItemsSource="{Binding Sentences}"    
         SelectionChanged="{Binding PickerCommand, Mode=TwoWay}" >
            <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
        </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Sentences is just a list of string in my ViewModel, how can I create a simple Commad for example that will just show a MessageBox with the current selected string in the ListPicker ?

Something similar to this function that i wrote in the code Behind :

```
private void PickerCommand(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (piker.SelectedItem != null) 
    {
      MessageBox.Show(piker.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }
}
```

EDIT :

I just created this simple function :

```
public void Test()
{
MessageBox.Show("Test!");
}
```

passed it :

```
PickerCommand = new RelayCommand<SelectionChangedEventArgs>(Test);
```

But I have the error saying that the argument that I passed is invalid, why is that ?

Comment: You don't need to bind the control to the event with that syntax. You just need: `SelectionChanged="PickerCommand"`

Comment: but how would you write such a command in the viewmodel ?

Comment: Create a property in your VM called SelectedSentence, bind that to SelectedItem.  You can inspect this within your VM, then act accordingly in your command.  Done.

Comment: can you write a code for this please? i still don't see how to do it i am new to mvvm

Comment: Sorry - my mistake, should have read twice - here is an example of what you want: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18199.event-handling-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application.aspx

Comment: thank you but the article you showed me is about a Button not selection_changed it is not the same

Comment: The point @Will is trying to make is that you use Delegates. It doesn't matter if its for a button or a drag or a w/e event

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:name="picker" ItemsSource="{Binding Sentences}">
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
        <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding PickerCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
```

and then

```
    public class MYViewModel :ViewModelBase
{
   public MyViewModel()
   {
       PickerCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(ActionForPickerCommand);
    }
    public ICommand PickerCommand {get;set;}
}
```

Use MVVM Light, that has some classes that help in it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what do I have to put instead of '<object>' Instead of 'ActionForPickerCommand'  I just put a 'public void function' that just displays a MessageBox but I get an error and how can I get the selected element of the ListPicker in the ViewModel with a RelayCommand ? thank you !

Comment: object should be the type of the object sent, not sure if is SelectionChangedEventArgs,

Comment: For the selectItem you need to create a propriety that will be binding to the picker SelectItem - TwoWays!!!

Comment: I edited my initial question can you please tell me why the function that I passed is invalid?